# how to get <td> value with span class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

My table is

```
<table id="ResumeWrite" class="Vasprice" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
       <th width="20%" class="bdrL_blue valignT highlight">
       <span class="font18">0 to 1 year Experience</span>
       </th>

       <th>
        <input type="button" value="submit"/>
       </th>
</tr>
```

i want to alert the value `0 to 1 year Experience` when i click the button. how to do in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by many ways. I think most simple is:

```
$(".font18").text();
$(".font18").html();
```

or

```
$("#ResumeWrite span.font18").text();
```

Last string only improves the accuracy of the finding desired item.

Comment: I have two or more <tr> with the same properties but different values within the same table.. If i use this code, it will show all table values. i want specific value/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="button"]')click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

alert($(".bdrL_blue").text());
});
```

and you can do by also following way

```
   $('input[type="button"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('span').text();
       //or
      $(this).closest('tr').find('th').text();
    });
```

**[see DEMO by all THREE WAYS](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/RsJP8/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).closest('tr').find('span').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Note, I didn't use the classes on the element to select it as they appear to be style classes, and not semantically linked to the content of the element.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RsJP8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ResumeWrite input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().prev().find('span').text())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c6jMm/)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(".font18").text());
```

or
    alert($("#resumeWrite .highlight span").text());
You should read the jquery doc, and follow some tutorial, it's very basic...